# How to merge the dependant dll (MySql.Data.dll) with my created exe?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, merge, odbc

I have created an application which requires the ODBC Connector to be installed on the computer to work. As my application need to connect to mysql database, it needs only one dll file (MySql.Data.dll) to work.

When i put this dll in the same location as the application it works ok. Now i want to merge this dll so that i will have only one Executable at the end ?

How can i merge this dependant DLL with my executable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a pure .NET module, you can try the `ilmerge` utility.

Comment: For sure, this is the 'easy' road, however to merge, you can embed their source. Make sure to remove all the stuff unrelated to the platform. For example, if desktop version, remove all the RT crap.  Also toss the extra stuff like csproj, sln, and AssemblyInfo.  In a nutshell, for this specific lib, you can merge directly, but it is a real PITA. because the desktop source tries to be everything for every platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, all assemblies will get referenced from somewhere...

- From the .NET framework path like:

> System.Net.dll

*All .NET apps need .NET Framework assemblies to run and that's why the user that want to execute your app needs .NET Framework installed. So your app knows where to find this assembly and won't need you to put, for example, the `System.Net.dll` assembly in the same path of your app for a success running.*

- Or from external paths like you app does.

*Your app knows where to find .NET Framework assemblies to run but wait! it needs also some extra dll to run, so that's why you get the `MySql.Data.dll` in the same path when compiling your app.*

**Possible solution:**

**1.** If you want to make just one executable try to use **Spoon Studio** (hard to find full cracked version and expensive to buy it). This will give you the possibility to embedded any assembly like the one you want or all .NET Framework, so this will make your app not dependant from any .NET Framework installation or needed assembly in the user computer that executes your app.

**2.** Try to use `ILMerge`, but please read below links to know if your code fits the requirements.

**How to and important information:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMerge.aspx